# Should I create my ReactNative App with Redux?

Tags: react-native, redux

I starting to learn ReactNative to develop Android and iOS Applications. Before that I programming Mobile-Applications with Java and Swift.

The last weeks I search a lot in the web to get experience from other developer that use ReactNative or other "Cross-Platform-Frameworks". Early I hear about Redux and that many developer use it.

I programming some examples in Redux to understand the concept, I have understood something but not quite everything.

So I come to my main question, is it better to programming a ReactNative App for both platforms with Redux ? What are the pros and cons ? And it is better for a beginner to start with ReactNative without Redux ?

Hopefully anyone can answer my question and share his experience, so I understand Redux better.

Comment: In my opinion it is a good idea to jump into redux straight away. However I'm afraid this is off topic for this forum, being primarily opinion based.

Comment: Even I'm thinking of making my react-native app in redux. One advantage I see here is, I can simply copy all my reducers, actions and sagas from my webapp to my mobile app because that is something which is not going to change at all (ofcourse sagas might have a few changes because of routing etc)

Comment: @viktor yes it is opinion based but I want to get the experience and opinions from other developers :)

Comment: @vishal okay this is nice so you have your own little library for your next application

Answer (score 2):

I'd say first get a good understanding of how React works and read about React best practices because thats what React Native uses to compose hierarchy of native views in React native app.

For a simple app you don't have to use Redux.You can always add it later.

https://blog.tighten.co/you-might-not-need-redux

Comment: This is a good answer,in my first days in ReactNative I learn the core concepts of React and how it works. I wrote this question because for me as a beginner I think it's easily to write a application without Redux because I understand more that happen and what I need to implemented.